# Safest way to store a laptop that's rarely used? Plugged in or not?

Tags: batteries, safety, laptop

I have a laptop (mid-2009 MacBook Pro: aluminum, non-user-serviceable battery) that I almost never use, but might need in the future.

The original battery was replaced by Apple a few years ago (The old one expanded)

Should I keep it plugged in or not? Which is least likely to cause the battery to turn into a fireball, like this one?

[image]

I don't have a yard or a fireproof safe, but one option is to store it in the oven (which I also rarely use), unplugged. However, as I understand it, totally draining the battery is also bad.

---

There was some discussion about this on [HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16736562), but I figured this site might have more expertise.

Comment: Darn, I have a laptop plugged in all the time and your picture scared the heck out of me.

Comment: @RobertEndl There's a scary video that goes with it :-) Click on "HN".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This applies to all battery appliances.

Appliances are not plugged in when stocked in a warehouse. They are charged to 50% and kept in a somewhat climate controlled environment. As in, no extreme heat or cold.

When you store the laptop, make sure it is powered off, and not in some standby mode. With the best case scenario the battery being unplugged.

The battery will still degrade, even if you do not use it. This is a chemical process that can only be slowed down by keeping it stable and not fully (dis)charged.

You could check, and possibly charge, the device every 6 months or so.

Related: [Recommendations from Apple.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201725)

---

Battery fires rarely occur from stable and unused batteries. They occur when:
- Deep discharging
- Fast discharging.
- Overcharging.
- Fast charging.
- Physical damage.
- Heat. *(caused by any of the above)*

Answer (score 2):

I change batteries (LI) to 100% and store them in the fridge (3-7 C) in the plastic bag (for humidity protection). Do not store laptop connected to the mains; store batteries and laptops separately. Note that laptops may have other smaller batteries inside keeping setup settings, and these batteries also die with the time. There may be rationale keeping this laptop for historical or retro reasons, otherwise consider selling it.

Worth checking for you if laptop is operational without big and small batteries - and if yes, then you may be sure that you have access to functional machine and your data even in 10 years when batteries will completely die of their age.

Comment: This particular model requires disassembly to remove the batteries (I mentioned this in the question). Would you keep the whole laptop (including HDs) in a plastic bag in the fridge? What's the upside, relative to room temperature?

Comment: If you really store device for quite a long period of time, it would be wise to remove battery anyway. Store laptop in room temperature, but battery in colder place with more or less constant temp. IMHO devices having non-removable batteries, and batteries not replaceable in the field, are not designed for long product life. I suspect it is the policy of Apple anyway.